# Fetching “id” from a view and pass to another view in Grocery Crud CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in Grocery Crud with Code Igniter and need a help. I have table vaboteni (emploees) and it work well. But I get stuck with code add more action. When I click to add action button I got error 404 Page Not Found. I want to fetch "id" from one row in table and pass to another view in order to display data for only one employee. I have site in local server, address localhost/bis_resursi/index.php/vraboteni/vraboteni_managment

Here is my Controller vraboteni.php

```
     function vraboteni_management()
     {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('vraboteni');
        $crud->set_subject('вработен');
        .....

        $crud->add_action('Преглед', '', 'vraboteni/vraboten_managment/pregled','ui-icon-plus');

        function pregled($id)
        {
            $this->load->model("vraboteni_pregled_model");
            $data["result"] = $this->getVraboteniPregled($vrabotenID);
            $this->load->view("pregled", $data);

        }

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
        }
```

and Models: vraboteni_pregled_model.php

```
        <?php
        class Vraboteni_Pregled_Model  extends CI_Model  {
            function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
        }

        function getVraboteniPregled($id){
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM vraboteni WHERE vraboteID = '$id' ");

            return $query->result();
        }
```

and in view vraboten_view.php I put

```
    <?=$query['vrabotenID']?>
    <br>
    Hi, I'am <?=$query['ime']?>
    <br>
    from<?=$query['adresa']?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find solution. Right code is:

Controller vraboteni.php

```
 $crud->add_action('Преглед', '', 'vraboteni/get','ui-icon-plus');

    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
    }


    function vraboteni()
    {
    $crud = new grocery_crud();

    $crud->set_table('vraboteni');


    $output = $crud->render();

    print_r($output);

    }

function getall()
{
    $this->load->model('vraboten_model');
    $data['query']=$this->vraboten_model->vraboten_getall();
    $this->load->view('vraboten_view',$data);
}
function get($vrabotenID)
{
    $this->load->model('vraboten_model');
    $data['query']=$this->vraboten_model->vraboten_get($vrabotenID);
    $this->load->view('vraboten_view',$data);
}
```

Models vraboten_model.php

```
<?php
```

class Vraboten_model extends CI_Model{

```
function vraboten_model(){
    parent::__Construct();
}

function  vraboten_getall(){
    $this->load->database();
    $query=$this->db->get(' vraboteni');
    return $query->result();
}
function  vraboten_get($vrabotenID){
    $this->load->database();
    $query=$this->db->get_where(' vraboteni',array('vrabotenID'=>$vrabotenID));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

}

and view vraboten_view.php

```
    <?=$query['vrabotenID']?>
<br>
Hi, I'am <?=$query['ime']?>
<br>
from<?=$query['adresa']?>
```